# How to Stop Encrypting process in external hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption

I Have an external 8T external hard disk on "encrypting" process since 10 days in my MAC ... and stuck in 27% ... 
* Seagate with APFS.
How can I stop the process and access to my info ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stop FileVault's decryption?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313109/how-do-i-stop-filevaults-decryption) https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210173/how-to-stop-decryption-of-external-drive?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, but it is and external hard drive, not the internal ( firevault )...

Comment: [FileVault Stuck on Pause](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/160161/filevault-stuck-on-pause) The answer by user155343 can be relevant. Also, use search https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bencryption%5d%20stop%20 for more questions :)

Answer (score 3):

There’s no option for stopping and reversing the encryption process. It doesn’t matter that it is an external drive, as it is still the same processs as is used when enabling FileVault on internal drives.

Note that if you unmount/unplug
the drive, encryption will be paused - but it resumes the next time it is plugged in.

In regards to accessing the content - you should be able to do this while the disk is encrypting. If you can not locate the disk in Finder, open Disk Utility to mount the external drive. You can use the drive as normally while it is encrypting - although performance will be impacted a bit.